# Excel VBA , all matching lines must return to listbox or combobox

Tags: vba, excel

i'm trying to run a code that is currently giving me the first matching line , but i would like it go give all the matching lines and not only the first one... And also if possible to show the matching results on a comboBox or a listbox.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
        Dim last, i As Integer
        Dim ref, refnovo, lote, armazem As String
        'Sheets("1_Ref.paraProtocolar").Visible = True
        Sheets("analisegeral").Select
        last = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("analisegeral").Range("H65536").End(xlUp).Row

        If UserForm1.OptionButton1 = True And UserForm1.OptionButton2 = False Then
            GoTo numnovo
            ElseIf UserForm1.OptionButton1 = False And UserForm1.OptionButton2 = True Then
            GoTo numvelho
        End If




    'NUMERO VELHO
numvelho:
    For i = 2 To last                     ' i é a linha, ciclo para fazer leitura dos utilizadores                      ' 3 e 4 colunas do utilizador e password
        armazem = Cells(i, 8)
        ref = Cells(i, 9)
        refnovo = Cells(i, 10)
        lote = Cells(i, 14)

    If TextBox1.Text = ref And ComboBox3 = armazem Then
    'TextBox2.Text = lote
    ComboBox4 = lote

    GoTo fim
    End If
    Next i
    If TextBox1.Text <> ref Then
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    MsgBox "Referência não encontrada!", vbInformation
    GoTo fim
    End If





    'NÚMERO NOVO
numnovo:
    For i = 2 To last                     ' i é a linha, ciclo para fazer leitura dos utilizadores                      ' 3 e 4 colunas do utilizador e password
        armazem = Cells(i, 8)
        ref = Cells(i, 9)
        refnovo = Cells(i, 10)
        lote = Cells(i, 14)

    If TextBox1.Text = refnovo And ComboBox3 = armazem Then
    ComboBox4 = lote
    GoTo fim
    End If
    Next i
    If TextBox1.Text <> refnovo Then
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    MsgBox "Referência não encontrada!", vbInformation
    GoTo fim
    End If




fim:
    End Sub
```

If anyone knows or has done something similar , i would be appreciated.

The user will insert a reference and if that reference has any number then it will give the number back , but some references have more than one number associated , that can go up to 3 numbers per reference , so the user will insert the reference and if there's 1 or more numbers , he must be able to choose from .

Comment: Note that `Dim ref, refnovo, lote, armazem As String` only declares the last one as `String`. All the others are automatically of type `Variant`. You need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim ref As String, refnovo As String, lote As String, armazem As String`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ComboBox4 = lote` you should be using `ComboBox4.addItem lote`. Also remove your `GoTo fim` inside the `for loop`'s because it will make you go to the end of the sub when you meet the conditions of the `if`'s the first time, hence giving you only the first match.

You should also use `ComboBox4 = ""` or an equivalent at some point of the beginning of your code, to reset your combo box whenever the code starts to run again.

Comment: If i remove `GoTo fim` then some part that i don't want to run will run anyways.